# Check which software is using the battery on my MAC

Tags: mac, battery

Whoever is familiar with the android system, probably knows about the utility that allows to check which app used the battery in percentage? 
Is there something similar for the mac? Of course, it would show which processes are using the battery over the last n hours.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like OS X Mavericks has implemented this in the Activity Monitor, which is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

A small bit of logic will help you work this out without needing software. Look at the power usage of an Android device and you'll see the screen is the main battery drain, followed by the OS being idle. It's only when you run an app for a very long period of time that it shows in the list as being a significant battery drain.

For example if I use my Nexus 4 as a satnav, the screen, network comms and the maps app jump to the top of the list. This is pretty obvious if you think about it.

On your Mac the main battery drain will be the LCD panel and its backlight. On my Lenovo X220 there is a Lenovo battery usage meter that shows current being drawn out the battery. I can adjust the laptop's power usage by several watts simply by adjusting the screen brightness. However running applications makes no noticeable difference.

I don't think Macs can do this (my old 2009 Macbook didn't) but your main power usage will be the screen. If your computer is idle and the CPU temperature is low then the CPU isn't drawing much power which means the software running in it won't be a significant factor.

External USB devices will also drain the battery more. Plug an external USB mouse in and you've just increased the power usage by at least 100mA. Try to sync your iPhone and you're now adding 2A of current drain to the system while it also charges.

Comment: That is not quite true. I agree that there are some obvious processes which drain my battery, but I often found out on my android about apps which had some issues and used much more battery than I wished and so I tried to find out why. Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: I would also like to add that if I remember correctly there was something like this in linux, although quite a bit more complicated. But I don't remember what it was.